# Angular2 DI Debug

Tags: debugging, dependency-injection, angular

Is there a way to debug Angular 2 dependency injection in the console to check the order of services created?

For example:

> Creating instance of "AuthService"...
>
> Creating instance of "UserService"...

I'm getting some strange errors like:

> reflective_provider.js:240 Uncaught Cannot resolve all parameters for
> 'ScaffoldStorage'(undefined, URLFileItemReader). Make sure that all the
> parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations
> and that 'ScaffoldStorage' is decorated with Injectable.

Maybe injector is trying to create MyService before AuthService (the service missing) or maybe I have interdependent services that im not aware of.. ( I have 20+ services in the app, not viable to list all here :( )

**Edit:**

1 - I forgot the simplest solution: write "console.log" in the constructor of each service..

2 - I just changed the import order and it worked.. Anyone knows why?

```js
# Before 
# ...
import { AUTH_PROVIDERS } from 'src/authentication';
import { SCAFFOLD_PROVIDERS } from 'src/scaffold';
# ...

# After
# ...
import { SCAFFOLD_PROVIDERS } from 'src/scaffold';
import { AUTH_PROVIDERS } from 'src/authentication';
# ...

# Boostraping: No change
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  # ...
  AUTH_PROVIDERS,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  SCAFFOLD_PROVIDERS,
  # ...
  provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: SHARED_DIRECTIVES, multi: true})
]).catch((error: Error) => console.error(error));
```

Comment: Is the `ScaffoldStorage` decorated with `@Injectable`?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, it's because the type of the first constructor parameter of your service can't be resolved.

For example:

```
import {SomeType} from './something'; // wrong import
import {URLFileItemReader} from './reader'; // rightimport

@Injectable()
export class ScaffoldStorage {
  constructor(private service:SomeType, private reader:URLFileItemReader) {
    (...)
  }
}
```

Comment: When "./something" doesn't exists, you say? In my situation it exists.. Because I just changed the order and it worked